# Why can't I tag some photos in Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I'm trying to tag some friends in a couple old photos I have on Google Plus, that were uploaded through auto-backup. But when I open the photo, the "Tag people" option does not show up. For other photos from a different set, the option does show up.

Why is it that the option does not show up in some pictures?

Comment: Is the album/set public or private?

Comment: They are photos in my auto backup,  not in an album nor shared yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't tag in the auto backup album.
When you tag someone you made the entire album visibile to the person tagged so G+ prevent you from trowing your privacy away.

Put those photos in an album and then tag your friends ;)

Comment: @Pablo you need to modify your question to be clear you're trying to tag a photo in the auto-backup album ;)

Comment: I don't see why they couldn't share only the single photo rather than the full album. Especially since the main reason I don't use albums as much is because they aren't prominent in the interface -- compared, for example, to the automatic highlights.

Answer (score 0):

**Tagging people in Google+ photos - on a desktop**

You can tag people from an album by licking on the Tag people on top right:

[image]

When you click on "Tag people" then the system searches for all human faces in those photos and also gives suggestions from Google+.  One can tag people in any image, also screenshots, just by clicking on the "Tag people" and adding a profile or Page name.

**NOTE:  If you tag someone in a photo, they get to see all other photos in that album.**

Tagging someone in just one image:

When you click open a photo in the lightbox view, on top you have some choices:

[image]

There you can also see "Tag people".

Tagging someone automatically is not always possible: It depends on the tagged person's settings.

More about tagging from Google:
https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1254833?hl=en

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Do check the privacy settings of the set you are trying to add tags to.

Comment: These photos are not shared. You mean they have to be shared before I can tag people?